# Attenuation estimation of the solution of the $n$-dimensional wave equation Cauchy problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, wave-equation, cauchy-problem

This is the equation given ($n\geq2$)
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt}=a^{2}\left(\Delta u\right), \\
\left.u\right|_{t=0}=\varphi(x_1,\cdots,x_n ),\\
\left.u_{t}\right|_{t=0}=\psi(x_1,\cdots,x_n ) .
\end{cases}$$
If $\varphi$ and $\psi$ have **compact support**  and satisfy the required smoothness conditions,  how to prove

$$|u(x_1,\cdots,x_n,t)|\leq C t^{-\frac{n-1}{2}}, \qquad t\to+\infty.$$

where $C>0$ is a constant.

Comment: Is $a$ a constant? If so, this is extremely well-studied. You can prove it using Fourier analysis ([Chapter 3 of my lecture notes](https://qnlw.info/course-notes/dispersive_notes/dispersive_notes.pdf)). You can also prove it using clever applications of Sobolev inequalities (Chapter 5 of the same lecture notes, for $n \geq 3$. The $n = 2$ case is trickier.) Both methods can be extended to variable coefficients case (with suitable assumptions) after a bit of hard work.

Comment: In odd dimensions it is also very easy to see the answer if you know the explicit representation formula for the solution to the wave equation (which is available when $a$ is a constant). In even dimensions the formula is a bit messier, and slightly harder to see. These are summarized in the first few pages of Sogge's book on Nonlinear Wave Equations.

Comment: Finally, for the result you quoted, you probably want to specify that $C$ is a constant depending on $\varphi$ and $\psi$ but independent of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. When you allow $C$ to dependent on $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, the decay rate is "faster than any polynomial".